# AWS S3 Buckets, iOS 9/8, request signature mismatch suddenly

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an iOS app that I worked on about a year ago and worked perfectly in downloading different assets from an S3 bucket. this was over 13 months ago.

Now I need to do some maintenance on the app and after opening up the code in xcode 7.3.1, and running it in the simulator I get a message about

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method
```

This message I get after downloading the assets, meaning I have about 3 mp4 files each of which are about 20 mb, and I can download them, but when the diownload is done and I go to the folder in simulator all 4 files would be 6kb each inthe folder and when I inspect the files I get this message

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method
```

My credentials have not changed, I am wondering whether this is related to iOS 9 SSL.

edit : 
Here is how I authenticate credentials in my app delegate

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider alloc] initWithRegionType:CognitoRegionType
                                                                                            identityPoolId:CognitoIdentityPoolId];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [[AWSServiceConfiguration alloc] initWithRegion:DefaultServiceRegionType
                                                                     credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager.defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```

all of the variables are in a globals file

```
 AWSRegionType const CognitoRegionType = AWSRegionUSEast1;
 AWSRegionType const DefaultServiceRegionType = AWSRegionUSEast1;
 NSString *const CognitoIdentityPoolId = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
 NSString *const S3BucketName = @"xxxxxxxxx";
```

Comment: Can you paste how you are you using the credentials for S3 access in your App? Just paste the syntax

Comment: What version of SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.3.6

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, a stupid error on my end

I was using AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest, I inadvertently added a content type to the download request,  which is not needed apparently, only if you upload to S3 you have to specify content type. After removing that line the code works and I can download !!

```
    AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest *getPreSignedURLRequest = [AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest new];
    getPreSignedURLRequest.bucket = S3BucketName;
    getPreSignedURLRequest.key = @"sometext";
    getPreSignedURLRequest.HTTPMethod = AWSHTTPMethodGET;
    //getPreSignedURLRequest.contentType = @"audio/mpeg"; this was the issue.
```